# How to know if a checkbox is checked onmouseover corresponding label

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I want to perform certain actions when hovering over checkbox-labels, but only when the checkboxes are checked.
How can I retrieve that information?

HTML

```
<input clrcheckbox="" type="checkbox" id="checks">
<label for="checks">Check</label>
```

JS

```
document.querySelector('label').onmouseover = () => {
    //so here should be something like:
    //if(checkbox is checked) {console.log('checked')}
    console.log('over');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution with jQuery

```html
<input clrcheckbox="" type="checkbox" id="checks">
<label for="checks">Check</label>
```

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    var isChecked = function(){
      if ($('#checks').filter(':checked').length > 0){
        console.log('Do some action')
      }
    }

    $('#checks').mouseover(isChecked)
    $('label').mouseover(isChecked)
  })
</script>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-sunset-nkq5q